/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/btrfs failed with return 1
When I boot, I get the following error:
/dev/root: Can't open blockdev

After a forced restart, I can boot using the advanced boot options:
With Linux 6.8.0-51-generic, the system will not boot.
With Linux 5.15.0-130-generic, the system boots successfully.

I have tried updating and upgrading, but the issue persists.
(Note: For debugging, I added sed -ex to /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/btrfs.)
root@x:~# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  kpartx libsgutils2-1.46-2 sg3-utils
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.142ubuntu25.4) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.142ubuntu25.4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-130-generic
+ PREREQ=
+ prereqs
+ echo
+ exit 0
+ PREREQ=
+ prereqs
+ echo
+ exit 0
+ PREREQ=
+ . /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hook-functions
+ [ -x /bin/btrfs ]
+ copy_exec /bin/btrfs /bin
+ local src target x nonoptlib ret
+ src=/bin/btrfs
+ target=/bin
+ copy_file binary /bin/btrfs /bin
+ local type src target link_target
+ type=binary
+ src=/bin/btrfs
+ target=/bin
+ [ -f /bin/btrfs ]
+ [ -d /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_SxPD4G//bin ]
+ target=/bin/btrfs
+ target=/usr/bin/btrfs
+ [ -e /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_SxPD4G//usr/bin/btrfs ]
+ mkdir -p /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_SxPD4G//usr/bin
+ [ -h /bin/btrfs ]
+ [ n = y ]
+ cp -pP /bin/btrfs /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_SxPD4G//usr/bin/btrfs
+ env --unset=LD_PRELOAD ldd /bin/btrfs
+ grep -P ^\t
+ sed -e
                /\//!d;
                /linux-gate/d;
                /=>/ {s/.*=>[[:blank:]]*\([^[:blank:]]*\).*/\1/};
                s/[[:blank:]]*\([^[:blank:]]*\) (.*)/\1/
+ echo /lib/libgcwrap.so
+ sed -e s#/lib/\([^/]*/\)\?\(tls\|i686\|sse2\|neon\|vfp\).*/\(lib.*\)#/lib/\1\3#
+ nonoptlib=/lib/libgcwrap.so
+ echo /lib/libgcwrap.so
+ sed -e s#-linux-gnu/\(tls\|i686\|sse2\|neon\|vfp\).*/\(lib.*\)#-linux-gnu/\2#
+ nonoptlib=/lib/libgcwrap.so
+ [ -e /lib/libgcwrap.so ]
+ copy_file binary /lib/libgcwrap.so
+ local type src target link_target
+ type=binary
+ src=/lib/libgcwrap.so
+ target=/lib/libgcwrap.so
+ [ -f /lib/libgcwrap.so ]
+ return 2
+ ret=2
+ [ 2 = 1 ]
+ return 1
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/btrfs failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-130-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools

Note: I also encountered an error with /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/dhcpcd which failed with return 1. I resolved this by reinstalling initramfs-tools.
Thank you in advance
